# Php version error when install composer

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, version, shared-hosting

I want to run composer on my shared hosting. When I install it, I have php version problem. It needs minumum version of 5.5. Then, my version seems 5.4. To solve it, I can siwtch it on Cpanel; however, there is no change from command line.

As a result, I don't have root privilege and I should switch php version from 5.4 to 5.5. What I should do to install composer?

Comment: Composer requires PHP 5.3.2+ to run. A few sensitive php settings and compile flags are also required, but when using the installer you will be warned about any incompatibilities. Reference https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. Composer will be installed with this command smoothly:

```
php [your composer.phar path] --install-dir
```